# javascript a link problems, passing correct values and not working in loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i have this code as i need to load a url.action with different parameters in a loop (multiple links)

Im having a couple of problems, first only the first link in the foreach loop actually does anything

Second problem is the controller is expecting id as an int and name as a string which isnt working so nothing loads? if i change the id and string in the 'link' manually it works

I have put both the values into a window.alert and it shows the javascript is getting the correct values, just dont think they are being recieved by the controller as correct string/int??

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#changetopicss').click(function () {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show();
    $('#flubestext').hide();

    var link = '@Url.Action("Detail", "Topics", new { @id = -1,  @name = -2, @forum = "all", @page = 0})';


          link = link.replace("-1", $(this).data('id'));
          link = link.replace("-2", $(this).data('shortname'));
 //   window.alert(dataname);
        $('#contentwrap').load(link, function () {
            $('#loadingAjaxs').hide();
            $('#flubestext').show();
            window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/topics');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Links created dynamically in a for each loop

```
<a id="changetopicss" data-id='@following.Id' data-shortname='@following.ShortName'>@following.Title</a>
```

Controller Header

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id, string name, string forum, int page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) changetopicss should be a 'class' not 'id' of the anchor. As id is expected to be unique across the page, only the first element with this id is selected and attached the click handler.

2) its safe to URLEncode strings before using them in URLs like in your code shortname could have space in it, use javascript's encodeURIComponent()

Comment: thanks brilal, do you know what the controller will see id and name as, string/int etc?

Comment: controller action will get whatever that action's parameter types are, there shouldn't be any problem with your code

Comment: if i put id = 304, name = "newest" in the urlaction it will work, if i use the link = linkreplace stuff it doesnt, have used window.alert and the right data shows in the alert popup. confused :S

Comment: when putting string in data-shortname or when getting this value in javascript to replace in url, you will have to urlencode the value, as the shortname may have spaces

Comment: just tried that with no success, ive even removed shortname out of the controller,javascript and route now as the id was all that was needed. so now if i put id as a number of a topic it works but doesnt when using link.replace 
    '@Url.Action("Detail", "Topics", new { id = -1, forum = "all", page = 0})'; if i set that to 304 which is a topic it works :s